# How do I set up a nameserver for my DynDNS address?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, nameserver, dyndns, dynamic-dns

I am trying to set up multiple sites under my DynDNS domain. I have a dynamic-ip and the only domain name I have is a free one from dydns, e.g. username.dyndns.org.

I only have one server, but I want to be able to host multiple sites from this one server.

This is what I have set up for bind,

```
zone "username.dyndns.org" {
    allow-query { any; };
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.username.dyndns.org";
};
```

/etc/bind/db.username.dyndns.org

```
$TTL 1d;

$ORIGIN username.dyndns.org. ;

@           IN  SOA ns.username.dyndns.org. joe.username.dyndns.org. (  
                    2011051300 ; serial number  
                    3h ; refresh  
                    10m ; retry  
                    1w ; expiry  
                    3h ; minimum  
                    )  
@       IN  NS      ns.username.dyndns.org.   
www     IN  CNAME   username.dyndns.org.  
mysite  IN CNAME    www
```

When I do `$ nslookup mysite.username.dyndns.org username.dyndns.org`, I get:

```
Server:     username.dyndns.org
Address:    12.23.56.78#53

mysite.username.dyndns.org  canonical name = www.username.dyndns.org.
Name:   www.username.dyndns.org
Address: 12.23.56.78
```

But if I do, `nslookup mysite.username.dyndns.org`, I get NXDOMAIN.

Here is the result of `dig @username.dyndns.org mysite.username.dyndns.org`:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.7.3 <<>> @username.dyndns.org mysite.username.dyndns.org 
; (1 server found) 
;; global options: +cmd 
;; Got answer: 
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 30676 
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 2 

;; QUESTION SECTION: 
;mysite.username.dyndns.org. IN A 

;; ANSWER SECTION: 
mysite.username.dyndns.org. 86400 IN CNAME www.username.dyndns.org. 
www.username.dyndns.org. 86400 IN   A   12.23.56.78 

;; AUTHORITY SECTION: 
username.dyndns.org. 86400  IN  NS  localhost. 

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION: 
localhost.      604800  IN  A   127.0.0.1 
localhost.      604800  IN  AAAA    ::1 

;; Query time: 1 msec 
;; SERVER: 12.23.56.78#53(12.23.56.78) 
;; WHEN: Sat May 14 11:23:49 2011 
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 153
```

But I get no answer if I do `dig mysite.username.dyndns.org` even though I get an answer for `dig username.dyndns.org`

I'm not sure what else to try. Any ideas?

*NOTE: Names and addresses have been changed to protect the innocent.*

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/154768/apache-dyndns-subdomain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Free dyndns does not support this, you need wildcard support - which is not free any more in dyndns.com.

A name server needs a fixed ip address, but wildcard support would be enough - no need for a name server on your end.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I ended up doing. No dns necessary. It's $15/year, which I think is fair considering I've been using their free service for 3+ years.